# Crackling sound when connecting camera to Raspberry Pi circuit

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, latch

Ok so hopefully I can get this to make sense. Basically I have a [Canon EOS 1D](https://www.canon.com.au/en-AU/Personal/Products/Cameras-and-Accessories/EOS-Digital-SLR-Cameras/1DMk4) camera. What I want to do is to be able to apply an accurate time-stamp to each image so I know when each picture is taken.

To do that, I hook the camera's external flash to the input of a S-R Latch. The output and reset signal are then connected to the GPIO pins of a raspberry Pi. The Pi senses the latch, grabs the GPS time from a 72 byte UDP packet across the local network, and applies the accurate time-stamp in a text file. It then sends out the reset signal to reset the latch. I have drawn a circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f49qwQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So I am under the belief that the external flash trigger on the camera is a contact closure switch. So when the camera takes an image, the switch closes and the latch triggers. The latch is powered by the Pi from one of its USB ports. [This](http://www.jaycar.com.au/Active-Components/Integrated-Circuits/Low-Power-Schottky/74LS02-Quad-2-in-NOR-Gate-IC/p/ZS5002) is the IC that I am using for the latch. There are also pull down resistors on the input pins so that everything stays low when it needs to and the latch works.

So here is my problem. Everything works fine. The latch works fine without the GPIO pins hooked up to the PI and with the GPIO pins hooked up. EXCEPT as soon as I hook up the camera I hear a cracking noise coming from the end of the wire connected to the camera (The other end is an audio jack) and the pwr LED on the PI no longer remains a constant red.

What could be causing this? The only places that the PI is connected to the circuit is through 2 GPIO pins and through the USB that powers the circuit. I have already wrecked a Pi from this and I don't really want to wreck another one. Please help

Comment: I think your camera is connecting a pin to ground, not completing a circuit with a switch. You should ground them together and use a pullup resistor rather than plugging 5V directly into your camera.

Comment: So you're saying that the cable that I have connected to the camera is sending 5V into the camera when it triggers?

Comment: @Passerby not accurate enough, and I need it in GPS time

Comment: @Passerby yes to the millisecond from a GPS, that is the way the boss wants it and I am not in a position to argue

Comment: I am a work experience student and this is what I have been assigned to do, everything works great expect when the camera is connected

Comment: So you have the latch/sensor connected to the Hot-Shoe Mount? And did you tie the grounds of the hot-shoe, latch, and usb/power together? A proper schematic would help.

Comment: @Passerby No the eos has a connecter on the side of the camera specifically for an exernal flash, the grounds on the pi and latch are together, but not the camera, the camera is powered by a separate 12v connector and the only thing connecting the camera to the latch is the external flash cable.

Comment: First, **IMMEDIATELY CEASE** your experiments, and do not resume them until you have figured out what is going on.  Camera flash units employ dangerously high voltages, and while a quick web search suggests the EOS external flash connector is intended for low voltages, something is going very wrong with your setup, so all bets are off.  Next, you don't need the SR latch - a GPIO interrupt will do fine.  But in a less than thoroughly engineered setup, you could potentially benefit from isolation, either optical or even via a small mechanical signal relay.

Comment: Yes, these will impose delay, but  probably *less* delay than using a non-realtime software stack on the pi will.  You could probably use an optical detector on the pi to see the flash itself (the same way a slave flash might), and so avoid any electrical connection to the camera at all.

Comment: As best I can find, the Prontor-Compur port is an open drain setup on the camera side. If you have it hooked up as mentioned, that seems wrong. And the rpi gpio is 3.3v not 5v so that's bad too.

Comment: As for the wrecked PI, check this article http://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/Raspberry_Pi_Dead/Raspberry_Pi_Fuse.html. I'm figuring the fuse may have been damaged by a short of the power supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could find, the Prontor-Compur Flash Sync port seems to be a open drain or open collector setup (Or SCR Thyristor). It simply pulls the Positive line low when the shutter is triggered. **I cannot link to any reliable source of this!** But based on a few arduino projects online which work with a slave flash, this seems to be the case. It's essentially the same exact circuit that the hot-shoe uses.

Below is an optocouple based setup. If you really want the latch, then just place it at the node GPIO instead. I suggest powering it from the RPI's 3.3V supply, to make it easier. If it needs 5V, then the output needs a voltage divider ***as the RPi GPIO are NOT 5V compatible***.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFB4QB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Logic here is REVERSED. The Camera will trigger the node RPi GPIO to go low when the picture is taken.

***I Highly suggest you measure the PC Port voltage and behavior first before connecting this*** as you may damage the Camera, or another RPi if I am wrong. Double check everything.